# According to ISKCON, what is the difference between Brahmavada and Mayavada?

Tags: advaita, brahman, maya, prabhupada, iskcon

As it is well known, ISKCON (and other Vaishnavas for that matter) strongly criticize philosophy of Advaita. Srila Prabhupada himself criticized Mayavada in his various commentaries on Vaishnava scriptures-

> "The Mayavadis say that the world created by maya is false, and that actually there is no living entity but only one spiritual effulgence. They further say that God is imaginary, that people think of God only because of ignorance, and that when the Supreme Absolute Truth is befooled by the external energy, maya, He becomes a jiva, or living entity. Upon hearing all these nonsensical ideas from the nondevotee, a devotee is greatly afflicted, as if his heart and soul were broken."  **Caitanya-caritamrta, Antya lila 2:99**

But at the same time Srila Prabupada said BrahmanVada is permitted in Vedas( But non-dual moksha is impermanent unlike Vaikuntha) as evident [here](https://vaniquotes.org/wiki/Mayavadi_philosophers,_they_think_the_Absolute_Truth_is_impersonal#/search). which says-

> Therefore they, these Brahmavādīs, these Nirākāravādī, although by austerities and penances they may rise up to the Brahman effulgence, still, they will fall down. Because we are living entities, we want varieties of enjoyment. We are not satisfied in void, in zero. That is not possible.         **Lecture on SB 1.2.18 -- Calcutta, September 26, 1974**

He even said that the Four Kumaras followed BrahmanVada.

My question is What is the difference between Brahmanvada and Mayavada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this](https://www.indiadivine.org/the-difference-between-brahmavada-and-mayavada/) site mentions,

> A brahmavadi is one who is tattva-vit, as defined in the shastras
>                     *vadanti ttva vidas
>            tattvam yaj jNaanam advayam
>                 brahmeti paramaatmeti
>                bhagavaan iti Sabdyate*
>   **Those who are tattva-vit understand that the Absolute Truth has three nondual features, namely Brahman, Paramatma, and Bhagavan. The mayavadis on the other hand say that the Absolute Truth is Brahman alone, and that Bhagavan is simply Brahman covered by illusion. Therefore they are known as the maya-vadis, because they believe Brahman gets covered by illusion.**
>   Brahmavadi means one who understands that all three features are the nondual Absolute, and he is therefore attracted to the Brahman feature. But such **a brahmavadi never commits the offense of saying that the Bhagavan feature is coverd by illusion. He perfectly understands the three features of the Absolute Truth to be nondual and non-material.**
>   *ekameva adviteeyam brahma*
>   “There is certainly only one Brahman, there are not two”.
>   This Brahman is described by Krishna in the Bhagavad-gita:
>   *mayatatam idam sarvam jagad avyakta murtina
>   mat stani sarvabhutani na caham tesvavastitah*
>   The Absolute Truth does have form, but Krishna says “avyakta murtina”, it is His unseen form. Therefore Brahman has form, but we cannot see it because we are in duality. The spiritual form is beyond our material vision.

As we can conclude from the above lines,A Brahmavadi is one who believes in Nirguna (Brahman) aspect of Brahman but doesn't rule out Sagun(Ishwar) aspect of Brahman as illusory or Maya.

Mayavadis, on the contrary believes that Saguna Brahman or Ishwar is illusory or Maya and their ultimate goal is to realize Nirguna or impersonal aspect of Brahman.

In short, A **BrahmanVadi** is one who (like mayavadi) is attracted to impersonal aspect of God but **never insults Ishwar(Krishna) by calling Him maya**.MayaVadi on the other hand **considers Ishwar as maya** and Nirguna Brahman as final goal.

Comment: This answer misrepresents the Advaita view of Ishwara.

Comment: This answer is from gaudiya vaishnava perspective obviously they have different views on Ishwar from advatins.

Comment: The site from which i have copied this answer is from Gaudiya Vaishnava perspective...it doesn't matter if it is against advaita notion of Ishwara.

Comment: @Partha yes...in vaishnavas considering Lord as Maya is considered a greatest sin one can commit

Comment: @Partha i agree these distinction i have found in Srila Prabhupada works..As he was founder acharya of ISKCON and clearly an authority for his devotees...i guess we can only  find this distinction in his words

Comment: @Partha Mayavadi literally means one who considers Everything as maya(including Lord)..

Comment: @Partha u want me to quote from iskcon scriptures?

Comment: @Partha well iskcon didn't coin the term...its vaishnavas way of addressing advatins...either way u wont find any defination of mayavada in sankara bhasyas...why would advatins call  themselves mayavadi?